# Fading out after fading in CSS

Tags: css

I'm currently working on a code for a friend but I'm having issues with fading and am unsure how to proceed to complete it. My main problem is getting the image to fade back in after fading out. The opacity will return to normal once my mouse is no longer hovering over the image. However, rather than fading, the transition is instantaneous, which doesn't look very nice.

```
.top {
    width: 580px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image:
    url(http://i.imgur.com/RSelpFd.png);
}
div:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

I know there are other ways to do this, but I'm still new to coding so I don't really understand them, so I was hoping there was a way to make what I've done work. Thanks ahead of time for the help.

Comment: you can try jQuery mouseenter mouseleave which is basically what hover is made of.

Comment: Please find your solution here https://jsfiddle.net/s9939LLm/1/

Comment: Just some changes and you good to go!! https://jsfiddle.net/1c6s90wm/

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is no needed. It's a very simple css implementation.

Hope this can help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/ggn89rp9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="top"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top {
    width: 580px;
    height: 250px;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    background-image:
    url(http://i.imgur.com/RSelpFd.png);
}
div:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/1c6s90wm/

Don't giving `hover` to the `div` rather give it to its class. Otherwise it ll work on all div tags

```
<div class="top"></div>


.top {
    width: 580px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image:
    url(http://i.imgur.com/RSelpFd.png);
   // opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease;

}
.top:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery could help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseover','div',function(){
        $(this).css('opacity',0);
        $(this).css('filter','alpha(opacity=50)');
        $(this).css('transition','all 1s ease');
    });
});
```

Note the 'hover' changed to 'mouseover' in jquery.